# How do you pass session object in TensorFlow v2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, eager-execution

I have a function `change_weight()` that modifies weights in any given model. This function resides in a different python file.

So if I have a simple neural network that classifies MNIST images, I test the accuracy before and after calling this function and I see that it works. This was easy to do in TensorFlow v1, as I just had to pass the Session `sess` object in the function call, and I could get the weights of this session in the other file.

With eager execution in TensorFlow v2, how do I do this? I don't have a Session object anymore. What do I pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by passing the `Model` object instead and getting the weights by `model.trainable_variables` in the other function.